# How to split data between 2 UITableViews on same View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As an example, I am trying to load a place name into my top `UITableView`, called `myTableView`. On the bottom, I am trying to display *only* "test2."

Naturally, all the data is being loaded into each `UITableView`. If I scroll to the bottom of `myTableView2`, the word "test2" IS shown, but I would like it to be the only thing there.

Is there a way, maybe by delegating different data sources, that I can separate the data I wan in each `UITableView`? I tried separating by if statements but quickly realized that had no effect.

It seems to me that I may need to set a separate datasource for `myTableView2`, but I am not sure how to do that...

Code is here:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

   [self setString];
   NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

   NSString *string1 = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];

   for (NSDictionary *diction in dic)
   {
      [array addObject:string1];
   }

   [[self myTableView] reloadData];

   NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test2"];

   [array addObject:string2];

   [[self myTableView2] reloadData];

   [indicator stopAnimating];
   indicator.hidden=YES;
   [indicator removeFromSuperview];
   ilabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

[image: myTableView on top, myTableView2 on bottom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the code below. The key was to have two different arrays to load the respective data in, and display it at the very bottom where I am able to distinguish between UITableViews with IF statements:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 [self setString];
 NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
 NSString *string1 = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
 NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test2"];

  for (NSDictionary *diction in dic)
  {
      [array addObject:string1];
      [array2 addObject:string2];

      [[self myTableView] reloadData];
      [[self myTableView2] reloadData];
  }

  [indicator stopAnimating];
  indicator.hidden=YES;
  [indicator removeFromSuperview];
  ilabel.hidden = YES;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if(!cell)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

 if (tableView == self.myTableView)
 {
  if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
  {        
    cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  }
  else
  {        
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  }
 }
 if (tableView == self.myTableView2)
 {
    if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
 }
 return cell;
}
```